# Should an expression of type ‘dynamic’ behave the same way at run-time as a non-dynamic one of the same run-type time?

Tags: c#, dynamic

Consider the following example program:

```cs
using System;
public delegate string MyDelegateType(int integer);

partial class Program
{
    static string MyMethod(int integer) { return integer.ToString(); }

    static void Main()
    {
        Func<int, string> func = MyMethod;

        // Scenario 1: works
        var newDelegate1 = new MyDelegateType(func);
        newDelegate1(47);

        // Scenario 2: doesn’t work
        dynamic dyn = func;
        var newDelegate2 = new MyDelegateType(dyn);
        newDelegate2(47);
    }
}
```

The first one works as expected — the conversion to `MyDelegateType` succeeds. The second one, however, throws a `RuntimeBinderException` with the error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<int,string>' to 'MyDelegateType'

Is there anything in the C# specification that allows for this behaviour, or is this a bug in Microsoft’s C# compiler?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Good catch Timwi.

Our support for *dynamic method groups* is weak. For example, consider this simpler case:

```
class C
{
  public void M() {}
}

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        dynamic d = new C();
        C c = new C();
        Action a1 = c.M; // works
        Action a2 = d.M; // fails at runtime
```

The `d.M` is interpreted as a *property get* (or field access) by the dynamic runtime, and when it resolves as a method group, it fails at runtime.

The same thing is happening in your case, it is just a bit more obscure. When you say `MyDelegate x = new MyDelegate(someOtherDelegate);` that is treated by the compiler just as if you'd said `MyDelegate x = someOtherDelegate.Invoke;`. The dynamic runtime piece does not know to do that transformation, and even if it did, it couldn't handle resolving the method group that is the result of the `.Invoke` portion of the expression.

> Is there anything in the C# specification that allows for this behaviour, or is this a bug in Microsoft’s C# compiler?

The spec does not call out that this should be a runtime error, and does imply that it should be handled correctly at runtime; clearly the implementation does not do so. Though it is a shortcoming of the implementation I wouldn't call this a "bug" because we deliberately made the behaviour you've discovered. We did not have the resources to make these kinds of expressions work exactly right, so we left them as errors. If we ever get a good way to represent method groups in the dynamic runtime, we might implement it.

Similarly there is no way in dynamic code to represent the notion of "this dynamic thing is a lambda expression where the types of the parameters are to be determined at runtime". If we have a good way to represent those in the future, we might do the work.

Sam talked a bit about this back in 2008; see his article on it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samng/archive/2008/11/02/dynamic-in-c-ii-basics.aspx

Comment: The root of the problem is that method groups are untyped, isn't it? Introducing a CaseDelegate, which can be invoked with different overloads, might be interesting, although it would require lots of different types for each possible combination of overloads.

Answer (score 2):

I've run in to this limitation too. Although I couldn't answer the why better than Eric Lippert, there is a straight forward workaround.

```
 var newDelegate2 = new MyDelegateType(x => dyn(x));
```

It implicitly gets the static signature from the delegate and the dynamic invocation works without any more info.  This works for delegates and, as a bonus, dynamic callable objects.

Comment: Yeah, but the downside of this is that the delegate invocation goes through the DLR *every time* you call it. I wanted it to be dynamic only once, when the delegate is set up; after that, it should just be a straight-forward invocation of a `MyDelegateType`.

Comment: True, but *every time* doesn't included an expression compile, that's just the first time, so when I did some runs with one million delegate calls, it avg 20 milliseconds slower using the dlr version and the max time of running a million calls was 130 milliseconds. However, if you know that your `dyn` variable is a `Delegate` you can always use reflection, you pay much more on creation, but since that's not a hotspot typically it would probably work out performance wise. `(MyDelegateType)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegateType),(object)dyn,"Invoke")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, performance isn’t the only issue with this. My main issue is that anything that uses ‘dynamic’ can throw in lots of different ways at run-time; in other words, it is not robust. If my application (which is a server) is misconfigured, it should throw during initialisation, not suddenly in the middle of operation as it receives an uncommon request that happens to trigger a corner-case.

Comment: I see what you mean, but that's more a fact you have to accept with the c# `dynamic` keyword in general. You can't test if a call will work at runtime until you call it. But certainly is a downside when you are only dealing with delegates.